# wchar_t pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, arrays

What's wrong with this:

```
wchar_t * t = new wchar_t;

t = "Tony";
```

I thought I could use a wchar_t pointer as a string...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is wrong with this code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080137/what-is-wrong-with-this-code) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577765/why-must-a-pointer-to-a-char-array-need-strcpy-to-assign-characters-to-its-array

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your code has two issues.

First, `"Tony"` is a pointer to a string of `char`'s.  `L"Tony"` is the appropriate wide string.

Second, you allocate a single `wchar_t` via new, then immediately lose track of it by reassigning the pointer to Tony.  This results in a memory leak.

Comment: To expand on Michael's explanation, the correct syntax would be `wchar_t* t = L"Tony";`.  This would declare a pointer and initialize it to point to the static (wide) string "Tony".

Comment: The syntax Should actually be `wchar_t const* t = L"Tony";`. To see why, consider the statement `*(t+1) = L'i';`

Answer (score 12):

A pointer just points to a single value. This is important.

All you've done is allocated room for a single `wchar_t`, and point at it. Then you try to set the pointer to point at a string (remember, just at the first character), but the string type is incorrect.

What you have is a string of `char`, it "should" be `L"Tony"`. But all you're doing here is leaking your previous memory allocation because the pointer holds a new value.

Rather you want to allocate enough room to hold the entire string, then *copy* the string into that allocated memory. This is terrible practice, though; never do anything that makes you need to explicitly free memory.

Just use `std::wstring` and move on. `std::wstring t = L"Tony";`. It handles all the details, and you don't need to worry about cleaning anything up.

Comment: IMO the most correct answer and, with using `std::wstring`, the best advice.

Answer (score 7):

Since you are a C# developer I will point out a few things c++ does different.

This allocates a new wchar_t and assigns it to t

```
wchar_t* t = new wchar_t
```

This is an array of constant char

```
"Tony"
```

To get a constant wchar_t array prefix it with L

```
L"Tony"
```

This reasigns t to point to the constant L"Tony" instead of your old wchar_t and causes a memory leak since your wchar_t will never be released.

```
t = L"Tony"
```

This creates a string of wide chars (wchar_t) to hold a copy of L"Tony"

```
std::wstring t = L"Tony"
```

I think the last line is what you want. If you need access to the wchar_t pointer use t.c_str(). Note that c++ strings are mutable and are copied on each assignment.

The c way to do this would be

```
const wchar_t* t = L"Tony"
```

This does not create a copy and only assigns the pointer to point to the const wchar array

Answer (score 5):

What this does is first assign a pointer to a newly allocated `wchar_t` into `t`, and then try to assign a non-wide string into `t`.

Can you use `std::wstring` instead? That will handle all your memory management needs for you.

Comment: wstring only exists in MSVC. It's not standard.

Comment: @Pavel: That is very wrong. wstring is `typedef`'ed as a `basic_string<wchar_t>` and exists on *every* compliant C++ system/toolchain.

Comment: @Pavel: §21.2/2: "The header `<string>` also defines two specific template classes `string` and `wstring` and their special traits."

Comment: @Pavel Radzivilovsky wstring is standard (at least the cppreference says it is http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/string/start and all wstring wstringstream,wcin,... classes work with g++) the only thing here could be microsoft not implementing the c++ standard.

Comment: They did implement a fairly-standard `wstring` back in '98, in their VC6 release. More recent versions have removed some minor non-compliances in their `wstring` implementation. (The most important was that `wchar_t` was a typdef in VC6)

Answer (score 0):

you can, its just that "Tony" is a hardcoded string, and they're ANSI by default in most editors/compilers. If you want to tell the editor you're typing in a Unicode string, then prefix it with L, e.g. `t = L"Tony"`.

You have other problems with your code, your allocation is allocating a single Unicode character (2 bytes), then you're trying to point the original variable to the constant string, thus leaking those 2 bytes.

If you want to create a buffer of Unicode data and place data into it, you want to do:

```
wchar_t* t = new wchar_t[500];
wcscpy(t, "Tony");
```

Comment: The size of a wchar_t is compiler specific and may be as small as 1 byte and as large as 4.

Answer (score -1):

this is completely wrong. 
There's no need to allocate two bytes, make t to point to them, and then  overwrite the pointer t leaking the lost memory forever.

Also, "Tony" has a different type. Use:

`wchar_t *t = L"Tony";`

IMHO better don't use wchars at all - See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049947/should-utf-16-be-considered-harmful

Comment: Also a wchar_t isn't necessarily two bytes.  In the version of gcc I'm using a wchar_t is 4 bytes, and the standard says it's compiler specific.  It can even be a single byte.